# How to return values from Function

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, return-value

I have created some simple code for my python practice. But when I try to return values from my function, I only get the first value and not both. What am I doing wrong?

```
def get_multi_data():
  #IM GETTING DATA FROM AN API as response#
  item_data = json.loads(response.text)
  #Get some data !!TEST!!
  item_info = []

  for name in item_data:
    item_name = item_data['market_hash_name']
    item_info.append(item_name)
    break
  else :
    item_name = None

  for price in item_data:
    item_price = item_data['prices']
    break
  else :
    item_price = None

  for lowest in item_price:
    lowest_price = item_price['lowest']
    item_info.append(lowest_price)
    break
  else : 
    lowest_price = None

  return item_name, lowest_price
```

When I'm trying to return my values, I'm getting only the first one. 
Thank you.

Comment: How are you calling it? You are returning two values, so if you want to get both in separate variables, you need to do: `a, b = get_multi_data()`. Otherwise `a = get_multi_data()` gives you both in a tuple assigned to `a`.

Comment: Could you paste the JSON data?

Comment: {"success":true,"base":2001,"market_hash_name":"toyota celica","prices":{"highest":27000.1,"lowest":1500.59,"last":2300.01},"created":1459185479,"updated":1461421472}

Comment: When I try to return only one, name or price I get the value, but I need to return both of then in the same time. Like return item_name, lowest_price but I only get the first one

Comment: @idjaw, I think the issue is that there are `break` statements in the for loops which stop after the "first one".

Comment: that was the wrong person to reply to... @DraugDev, why do you have the `break` statements where they are?

Comment: @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen becouse when not, it throws an error: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` in my 3. `for` loop

Comment: oh I see, so if `item_data` is empty you get the `else:` on the for loop to run, otherwise it uses the data, that would be better represented as `if item_data:` and `if item_price:` (with `break`s removed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pick which value you want when calling the function. Treat the function like a list:

```
a = get_multi_data()[0]
```

sets `a` equal to `item_name`
or:

```
a = get_multi_data()[1]
```

sets `a` equal to`lowest_price`

as some of the comments have pointed out you can also just take the return value as a tuple.

Comment: It looks like im too dumb for this one. What does `a = get_multi_data()[0] ` mean? How to use it in code, sorry im new in Python.

Comment: A more proper way to deal with this is `a, b = get_multi_data()`. You are returning two values, so you should take both of them and deal with them accordingly.

Comment: good point from @idjaw. This is returning the value as a tuple as I mentioned in the answer. Putting the square brackets just selects an index. To use this code literally just type it out when calling the function and the values will be assigned to `a`  and `b`. If you still don't understand then try and be more specific as to what is tripping you up.

Comment: @gjttt Look, I'll try to explain. I'm getting my values from an API, I already posted what kind of stuff im gettin from it. Then I try to get from this stuff only 2 values, NAME and LOWEST_PRICE. When I try to return only one of them, I get my values, its fine. But I need to return both of them like `toyota celica, 1500.59`. When I add `get_multi_data()[0]` or `[1]` im gettin only one. When I try to `return item_name, lowest_price` im getting only the first one. So I dont realy know what to do.. or what im doing wrong (I think a lot...)

Comment: then do what @idjlaw said to and return them to tow different values! `a, b = get_multi_data()`. This means that `a` is equal to `item_name` and `b` is equal to `lowest_price`. Try typing `a, b = get_multi_data()` and then printing `a` and `b`.

Comment: @DraugDev, you keep saying "first one" and I think everyone else is assuming you mean "item_name but not lowest_price" but that isn't making sense because `return item_name, lowest_price` **does** return both values in a tuple.  If you mean something other then that by "first one" could you try to explain it in different words?

Comment: @DraugDev have you typed out `a, b = get_multi_data()` and then printed `a` and `b`? or even just `print(get_multi_data())`. This will show you both of the values

Comment: @gjttt1 thats what im getting when im trying to do it  `line 22, in get_price_data item_name = item_data['market_hash_name'] KeyError: 'market_hash_name'`

Comment: KeyError means that you are searching the `item_data` dictionary for a key that it doesn't contain('market_hash_name'). This means that the line `item_data = json.loads(response.text)` isn't doing what you expect it to. You will need to look into how the `json.loads()` function works and how it is loading the data and then go from there!

Comment: @gjttt1 thank you. I'll try to do my best. Thank you again.

Comment: @DraugDev if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.